# Default Map in Generics in jdk 1.5

Tags: java

I want default Map to use all HashMaps. 
key can be String, integer or any data type
Value can be String, Integer ..any data type.

How to use Map in jdk1.5.

Comment: That JDK has reached the end of its useful life.  Time to upgrade to JDK 6.

Comment: Irrespective of JDK5, I don't understand the question. If you want a HashMap to use any kind of data, you can say `HashMap<Object, Object>`.

Comment: Thilo, we need to use Map as a reference. Can i use Map<Object,Object> MapA = new HashMap<Object,Object> ??

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.5 the [Java language includes Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) as a way to add type safety to various collection classes.  This means that you have to declare what types a collection will store using the "pointy braces" notation, e.g `Collection<String>`.

Note also that the [Map type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and the [HashMap type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a concrete class, so typically you declare variables to be of an interface type and the contained instances to be specific classes.  This way you can change your mind about the implementing class without having to change the way the data structure is accessed.  For example:

```
Map<Object,Object> m = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

Note that you can also choose not to use the type parameterization but the compiler will probably warn you.  Additionally, you can use the `?` wildcard to achieve a similar effect:

```
Map m2 = new HashMap();
Map<?,?> m3 = new HashMap<?,?>();
```

You can also use the `extends` keyword in this context to achieve finer grained type control:

```
Map<? extends Object, ? extends Number> m4 =
    new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```